# PhpStorm - Xdebug, Waiting for incoming connection idekey

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I've searched a lot for this problem when debugging php using PhpStorm 2016.3 with xdebug, but still not working with error "Waiting for incoming connection idekey xxx".

php.ini

[image]

PhpInfo

[image]

[image]

Debug Settings

[image]

Server Config

[image]

And Run Config

[image]

I have already enabled the "Listening for PHP debug connections".

Any help highly appreciated, thanks all !

Comment: your port setting is 8000 in PhpStorm, but 9000 in xdebug section of php.ini.

Comment: Also, if you use php-fpm, stay away from 9000 for xdebug.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I try to changed all port to 8000 but still don't work

Comment: 1) Port `8000` is OK there -- it's a server port and not xdebug 2) Since you are on Windows it's quite safe to use `9000` for xdebug .. but you can always change it to be `9001` in both php.ini and PhpStorm if you want to be safer (9000 is used by php-fpm by default). 3) DO NOT use xdebug 2.5 RC -- better use **xdebug 2.4.1** for now (e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205972064/comments/205080264)

Comment: @LazyOne I changed xdebug version to 2.4.1 and port 9001 both php.ini and PhpStorm but still don't work :(

Comment: I coding in Php Storm 2016.3 EAP