# Xdebug cant connect through to my IDE

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

Today I've installed xdebug and set config:

```
; Enable xdebug extension module
; see http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0


xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

After I configure my IDE and validate remote xdebug

[image: picture of validate results]

but when I'm trying use it in my code (with breakpoints) xdebug cant connect

```
Log opened at 2016-11-19 20:34:42
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 94.181.237.21:9000.
W: Creating socket for '94.181.237.21:9000', poll: Operation now in progress.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-11-19 20:34:42
```

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: i using elementaryOs i think no firewall here @user2182349

Comment: As I understand you are using **xdebug 2.5** (RC)? if so -- use stable **2.4.1** as 2.5 has some connectivity issues sometimes (at least on Windows platform: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205972064/comments/205080264). Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40668606/783119

Comment: @LazyOne i try it, but now i change 1 setting for forwarding pot in my router and xdebug start working, but i can't use becouse in my network not only i debugging

Comment: @AlexKuvaev What exactly did you do so it's working now? Try other options maybe -- [SSH tunnel](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Remote+debugging+in+PhpStorm+via+SSH+tunnel) or [DBGp Proxy](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Multi-user+debugging+in+PhpStorm+with+Xdebug+and+DBGp+proxy)

Comment: @LazyOne, I add virtual server in my router for forward 9000 port, but this is not ideal solution for me, because in my lan not only i want to debug.
I think it's my bad in server configuring, but i don't know where :)

Comment: @LazyOne i try tunnel with command `ssh -R 9000:5.167.164.169:9000 admin@95.215.111.77` but xdebug does not stop at breakpoint

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283171/using-xdebug-through-docker-container-in-phpstorm?rq=1#answer-44284500