# Using xdebug through Docker container in PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, docker-compose, xdebug

I've read some posts about this but none helped in my case or simply overlooked the missing piece.

I cannot get xdebug to work on PhpStorm using a Docker container.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    - ./nginx/logs:/var/logs/nginx
    - ./nginx/site-enabled/default.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    depends_on:
    - php

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_DATABASE: local_db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"

  php:
    build: images/php
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/share/nginx/html
    - ./config/docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - ./config/docker/php/ext-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
    - ./config/docker/php/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
    user: www-data
    depends_on:
    - db
```

**config/docker/php/ext-xdebug.ini**

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php7/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.overload_var_dump=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_host=172.20.0.1 # ip of host inside docker container
xdebug.remote_log=/usr/share/nginx/html/xdebug.log
```

**error from xdebug.log**

```
Log opened at 2017-05-31 11:01:14
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.20.0.1:9000.
W: Creating socket for '172.20.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2017-05-31 11:01:14
```

In PhpStorm I'm using remote debugger with following settings:

**server**

```
Host - 127.0.0.1  
Port - 80
```

**Absolute path on server**

```
/usr/share/nginx/html
```

**IDE session key**

```
PHPSTORM
```

Comment: kill phpstorm, and check on your host if port 9000 is used by another process. If it is, you may need to change the xdebug port in both the php settings, and in your phpstorm.

Comment: there is no process which uses this port, except phpstorm when started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got the solution in here

https://forums.docker.com/t/ip-address-for-xdebug/10460/9

I had to set my internal ip to `xdebug.remote_host` and disable `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0`

Seems this is a osx thing.
Hope this helps someone here

Comment: How do I find the internal ip? Thx

Comment: In windows, to get the internal IP, type `ipconfig` in `cmd` and check the `DockerNat` IP

Comment: I had the similar problem on Windows 10 and this was also the solution

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the following config on `ext-xdebug.ini` works for Docker for Mac

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

Docker automatically defines `host.docker.internal` within containers. So we simply point xdebug to think `host.docker.internal` is the IP of host machine (which obviously is). This way, we don't have to rely on ever changing internal IP between docker container and host.

More information can be found here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds